# Problema al instalar fuentes en manjaro

Tags: linux, fuentes, manjaro, archlinux

He instalado un pack de fuentes en mi `.local/share/fonts` son como 2000 fuentes luego de hacer el `fc-cache` todas las fuentes quedan disponibles en mis programas de edicion Inkscape, LibreOffice etc. Pero tambien me modifica la forma en que se muestran las pag web en los navegadores que tengo instalados, es como que cambia las fuentes por defecto, logicamente al borrar las fuentes de mi carpeta local y hacer nuevamente el `fc-cache` todo regresa a la normalidad, pero es muy incomodo instalar para trabajar y desintalar cuando necesito ingresar a alguna web.
A alguien le ha pasado algo igual, alguna sugerencia.
Mi sistema operativo actualmente es MANJARO

```
█     OS: Manjaro 20.1 Mikah
 ██████████████████  ████████     Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.7.17-2-MANJARO
 ██████████████████  ████████     Uptime: 38m
 ████████            ████████     Packages: 1356
 ████████  ████████  ████████     Shell: bash
 ████████  ████████  ████████     Resolution: 1024x768
 ████████  ████████  ████████     DE: Xfce4
 ████████  ████████  ████████     WM: Xfwm4
 ████████  ████████  ████████     WM Theme: Matcha-sea
 ████████  ████████  ████████     GTK Theme: Adwaita [GTK2]
 ████████  ████████  ████████     Icon Theme: Papirus-Light
 ████████  ████████  ████████     Font: Noto Sans Light Italic 10
 ████████  ████████  ████████     Disk: 49G / 141G (37%)
                                  CPU: Pentium Dual-Core E5300 @ 2x 2.612GHz
                                  GPU: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 10)
                                  RAM: 2012MiB / 3236MiB
```

Comment: Sé que la pregunta posiblemente no sea on-topic del sitio pero pues, tampoco tenemos superuser en español... te pregunto: ¿cuál es el problema en sí cuando añades las fuentes? Estás reemplazando fuentes? Si tienes, digamos DejaVu Sans por defecto en firefox y no la mueves, no debería haber ningún problema al presentar sitios web y demás. Cómo estás manipulando los archivos que ya están en el directorio?

Comment: Gracias por constestar, yo no estoy reemplazando fuentes, de hecho las fuentes del sistema se mantienen en `/usr/share/fonts` y yo estoy agregando mis fuentes en carpetas con nombre `fuentes1` y `fuentes2` pero lo estoy haciendo dentro de mi carpeta de configuacion local `.local/share/fonts` en esa carpeta no habia nada ahorita si hay porque como solucion temporal me he instalado las fuentes de google desde el repositorio de github y esas si no me han presentado problemas.. soy si se quiere bastante novato usando linux y lo que me ocurre es que al hacer `fc-cache` empieza el desorden

Comment: Es que, si uno mira la [wiki oficial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts#Manual_installation), efectivamente uno puede montar las fuentes a mano en el directorio que señalas para que tu usuario las tenga a mano. También señalan que correr `fc-cache` no es necesario. ¿Has probado usar las fuentes _nuevas_ sin correr esa actualización del font cache? Lo otro es que tal vez, alguna de las aplicaciones caiga en lo que pide la sección _Older applications_ en la misma wiki...

Comment: eso no lo he probado, voy a intentar hacerlo en este momento a ver quetal me va.

Comment: Las fuentes que estoy usando las dejo en el siguiente link a ver si de pronto logran visualizar algun error [DESCARGAR FUENTES DISEÑO GRAFICO](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dsEzxeUyGX6bEs31E0ZwR8SpThi8wAGz/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: En efecto he seguido las recomendaciones de la [Wiki de Archlinux ](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts_(Espa%C3%B1ol)) yo porque vengo de usar Debian, Ubuntu y Linux Mint y ese error no se me habia presentado Gracias por ayudarme a solucionar mi problema..!

Comment: Vale, te voy a dejar ese comentario como respuesta y pues márcalo como aceptado. Me alegra que te funcionara :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si uno mira la [wiki oficial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts#Manual_installation), efectivamente uno puede montar las fuentes a mano en el directorio que señalas para que sólo tu usuario las tenga a mano.
También señalan que correr `fc-cache` no es necesario (pues se gestiona de forma automática).

> To install fonts system-wide (available for all users), move the folder to the /usr/share/fonts directory. The files need to be readable by every user, use chmod to set the correct permissions (i.e. at least 0444 for files and 0555 for directories). To install fonts for only a single user, use ~/.local/share/fonts/ (~/.fonts/ is now deprecated).
>
> ...
>
> Then update the fontconfig font cache: (usually unnecessary as software using the fontconfig library does this)
>
> ```
> $ fc-cache
> ```

¿Has probado usar las fuentes nuevas sin correr esa actualización del font cache? Lo otro es que tal vez, alguna de las aplicaciones caiga en lo que pide la sección *Older applications* en la misma wiki

> Older applications
>
> With older applications that do not support fontconfig (e.g. GTK 1.x applications, and xfontsel) the index will need to be created in the font directory:
>
> ```
> $ mkfontscale
> $ mkfontdir
> ```
>
> Or to include more than one folder with one command:
>
> ```
> $ for dir in /font/dir1/ /font/dir2/; do xset +fp $dir; done && xset fp rehash
> ```
>
> Or if fonts were installed in a different sub-folders under the e.g. /usr/share/fonts:
>
> ```
> $ for dir in * ; do if [  -d  "$dir"  ]; then cd "$dir";xset +fp "$PWD" ;mkfontscale; mkfontdir;cd .. ;fi; done && xset fp rehash
> ```
>
> ...
>
> To check that the font(s) is included:
>
> ```
> $ xlsfonts | grep fontname
> ```
>
> Note: Many packages will automatically configure Xorg to use the font upon installation. If that is the case with your font, this step is not necessary.
>
> This can also be set globally in /etc/X11/xorg.conf or /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d.
>
> Here is an example of the section that must be added to /etc/X11/xorg.conf. Add or remove paths based on your particular font requirements.
>
> ```
> # Let X.Org know about the custom font directories
> Section "Files"
>    FontPath    "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi"
>    FontPath    "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi"
>    FontPath    "/usr/share/fonts/cantarell"
>    FontPath    "/usr/share/fonts/cyrillic"
>    FontPath    "/usr/share/fonts/encodings"
>    FontPath    "/usr/share/fonts/misc"
>    FontPath    "/usr/share/fonts/truetype"
>    FontPath    "/usr/share/fonts/TTF"
>    FontPath    "/usr/share/fonts/util"
> EndSection
> ```